# How to define a variable which can be accessed by all my functions in my object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I have a object like this:

```
myobj={
  //where to define Car car=new Car();
  test:{
    testFunc1(){car.paintTest();},
    testFunc2(){car.drawTest();}
  },

  use:{
    useFunc1(){car.paintUse();},
    useFunc2(){car.drawUse();}
  },
};
```

I will use `myobj` in the way that, in another js file, I can easily call

`myobj.test.testFunc2();`

or

```
myobj.use.useFunc1();
```

As you notice, in `myobj`, I have a `car` instance frequently be used **in different functions in different sub-objects** (e.g. "test", "use" sub-objects).

I am wondering, where can I define `Car car=new Car();` in `myobj` so that the `car` is defined **once** and can be used in **several** functions in `myobj`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that like this:

```
myobj={
  car: new Car(),

  test: {
    var self = this;
    testFunc1(){self.car.paintTest();},
    testFunc2(){self.car.drawTest();}
  },

  use: {
    var self = this;
    useFunc1(){self.car.paintUse();},
    useFunc2(){self.car.drawUse();}
  },
};
```

**UPDATE**

working version with fake `Car` object:

```
function Car (){
    this.paintTest = function(){console.log('painttest')}
    this.drawTest = function(){console.log('drawtest')}
    this.paintUse = function(){console.log('paintuse')}
    this.drawUse = function(){console.log('drawuse')}
}

myobj = {
  car: new Car(),

  test:{
      testFunc1: function() {myobj.car.paintTest();},
      testFunc2: function() {myobj.car.drawTest();}
  },

  use: {
      useFunc1: function(){myobj.car.paintUse();},
      useFunc2: function(){myobj.car.drawUse();}
  },
};

myobj.test.testFunc1();
myobj.test.testFunc2();
myobj.use.useFunc1();
myobj.use.useFunc2();
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/KcQvL/

Comment: @Mellon i just tryed out your orig code in jsfiddle and it does not even work... it might work with `this`. i just use self alot in my code